# Trying to add users from Group A to Group C but not if they are members of Group B

Tags: powershell

Long time reader first time poster... :)

I'm getting all confused. So, I'm trying to add users that are in GroupA and not in GroupC but also exempt them if they are in GroupB. I'm using this script:

```
$OUs = 'OU=TestOU,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=local'
$ExemptGroups = (Get-AdGroup -filter * | Where {$_.name -like "Exempt Groups B and C wildcard"} | select name -expandproperty name)
get-aduser -filter * -searchbase $OUs | where-object {((get-aduser $_.samaccountname -properties memberof).memberof -eq "Group A") -and ((get-aduser $_.samaccountname -properties memberof).memberof -eq $ExemptGroups)} | ForEach {add-adgroupmember -identity "Group C" -members $_.samaccountname}
```

Im not getting any errors with a test user in the test OU but its also not adding them to the desired Group C

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to add group a members that are not in group b to group c?

Comment: Lets assume Group A members are "Domain Users". So if they are in Domain Users (which they should all be) are not in Group C, add to Group C. If they are in Group B, do not add to Group C. Im not sure if the Group A requirement is me overthinking it or completely unnecessary. Im sure its both. :)

Answer (score 0):

No need to query AD a bunch of times, we can query it once and then slice the results as we need it.

```
$OUs = 'OU=TestOU,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=local'
$users =  Get-AdGroup -filter * -properties memberof
```

I think it would be easier to hit AD and cache the results, then filter the results to all the GroupB members and store that as GroupB members.

```
#gives an array of users in Group B
$GroupBMembers = $users | Where {$_.memberof -eq "Group B"} | select -expandproperty name
```

Then we look at the cache again and now filter it for anyone who IS NOT in GroupB members.

```
$NewGroupCMembers = $users | where {$_.Name -notin $GroupBMembers }

#...add NewGroupCMembers to Group C
```

Now all that's left is to add the people in `$NewGroupCMembers` to group C and you're done!

Comment: Awesome. I shall give it a try. I’m not a coder by any stretch of the imagination but all that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

@FoxDeploy Ok this is what I have cobbled together with your help:

```
$OUs = 'OU=TestOU,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=local'
#
# Query users of groups for membership
$users = Get-ADGroup -filter * -properties memberof
#gives an array of users in Group B
$GroupBMembers = $users | Where {$_.memberof -eq "GroupB"} | select -expandproperty name 
#Filter users not in GroupB group
$NewGroupCMembers = $users | where {$_.Name -notin $GroupBMembers }
#Add new group members to GroupC
$OUs | ForEach {add-adgroupmember -identity "GroupC" -members $NewGroupCMembers -WhatIf}
```

Running with "WhatIf" the output seems ok:

> What if: Performing the operation "Set" on target "GroupC".

Running without WhatIf, I get an error:

> add-adgroupmember : A global group cannot have a universal group as a
> member At line:20 char:17
>
> - ...  | ForEach {add-adgroupmember -identity "GroupC (I think because its cut off) ...
> - ```
>               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (GroupC:ADGroup) [Add-ADGroupMember], ADException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8517,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember

Comment: I'd do this instead `Add-ADGroupMember -identity "GroupC" -members $NewGroupCMembers`.  You don't need the `ForEach` on your last line.